# How do I find High PR blogs on for a keyword?

Tags: seo

I want to search for high page rank sites on a particular keyword.Please tell me how can I do so.Thanks

Comment: Despite my answer, your question is too broad, if a question at all (no question mark). What I understand your question to be is how to use Google?

Comment: @Eli: I was wondering if people use a particular software for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page Rank is just one of the 200+ indicators Google uses.  It isn't even the strongest one. Also, Google only releases Page Rank several months later.  Meaning, when you see a Page Rank for a site it is probably the Page Rank the site had around 4 months ago.

Google's Toolbar will let you see the Page Rank for a specific site. This site also lets you do a search see what the page rank of a specific URL is, http://www.prchecker.info/check_page_rank.php.

Answer (score 1):

Type that keyword into Google. For example if you wanted to see sites that rank well with the keyword Java, you would do this:

http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Java

And there you go.

Comment: Thanks.I tried to google and see the top pages,but I was actually looking for high page rank blogs and from where I could use my signature.

Comment: He said PAGE rank not SERP placing. You shot him down too quick.

Comment: For blogs specifically, try http://blogsearch.google.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a reasonable question to ask. The sites with the highest PR don't necessary all sit at the top of the Google rankings. I've actually been looking for something similar because I want to find high PR sites for a certain keyword so I can see where the link-love is coming from for that keyword.

I'm gonna sign up for this in the new year in the hope that it will help: http://www.seomoz.org/cart/purchase_select

Comment: hay! that takes $$ : (

Comment: Yeah, but could be well worth it if I get a big jump in rankings and seomoz do know their stuff

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to find those high PR blogs by using some kind of software. I will suggest to collect some URLs manually.